# Cakephp 1.3 email component won't send using a "from" or "sender" that i want it to! (on ubuntu 10.04!)

Tags: email, cakephp, ubuntu, sender

I can send an email via cakephp 1.3. What I cannot seem to do is change the "from" portion - so!

Given:

```
 $this->Email->from = "no-reply@someurl.com"; 
//OR
 $this->Email->from = "no-reply<no-reply@someurl.com>"; 
...
$this->Email->send();
...
```

this doesn't work. Sending to gmail just has a fun "unknown user" value as the "from" or "sender".

To be clear, I have only one of those $this->Email->from lines, not both!

In the end, I had to go to the email.ctp component in cakephp - cake/libs/controller/component/email.ctp - and change the line 543 from:
    $headers['From'] = $this->_formatAddress($this->from);
to:
    $headers['From'] = 'no-reply';

Any ideas why i has to do all this? I read online about the aliases file and some sort of setting in the php.ini - i'm running ubuntu 10.04 - but i didn't touch them. 
Actually, if anyone knows what I would do with the /etc/aliases file, or what to do with the php.ini file, that would also be awesome.

cheers!

PS note in the above that my email component is defined as:

```
'Email' => array (
    "delivery"=>"mail",
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example should work. However, the second is not up to the [RFC standard](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html). You need the all important space.

```
$this->Email->from = "no-reply <no-reply@someurl.com>";
```

Check the [Cake Book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1286/Sending-a-basic-message) form more detail on the Email component.

Comment: sigh thanks for the response - i didn't know about the rfc standard. This doesn't quite fix whatever my cakephp is up to, but at least it is compliant!

Comment: If this didn't fix your problem, don't mark it answered. From your code, I don't see an issue. It's somewhere else in your code.